# How to make a continous input in python that registers all input

Tags: python-3.x, user-input

I am writing a code which needs quick and quick input. Like playing a piano. The problem is that the input has to always be active and every time someone types something my code has to realise that.

so: `Input1 = input("Enter something: ")` when I then type `a` the code has to see that even though I do not press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. But this has to work for infinite time.

Comment: You must use the `input` function? Which is your OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to implement the [`pynput`](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/) module:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
    print(f'{key} pressed')

def on_release(key):
    print(f'{key} release')
    
    #Stop the listener
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

# Collect events until released
with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Take a look to the reference [monitor the keyboard](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html#monitoring-the-keyboard)